# What is the difference between concepts Custom Task and Enhanced Task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, task, concept

I often meet in Gradle documentation these concepts. What is the difference between them?

From what I know custom task is class that encapsulates some logic, but what is enhanced task and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `simple task` in Gradle is an instance of [DefaultTask](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) and does not do anything out of the box. To make it do something you have to add code to the task definition in your build script.

An `enhanced task` is an instance of a different class (for example a Copy task is an instance of [Copy](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Copy.html)) and has some behaviour out of the box. You just need to configure that behaviour in your build script (eg tell it where to copy from and to)

A `custom task` is an enhanced task that is an instance of a class you wrote yourself.

Answer (score 2):

An enhanced task is defined in the Gradle manual as:

> Gradle supports enhanced tasks, that is, tasks which have their own properties and methods. This is really different to what you are used to with Ant targets. Such enhanced tasks are either provided by you or are provided by Gradle.

It also says:

> Gradle supports two types of task. One such type is the simple task, where you define the task with an action closure. We have seen these in Chapter 6, Build Script Basics. For this type of task, the action closure determines the behaviour of the task. This type of task is good for implementing one-off tasks in your build script.
>
> The other type of task is the enhanced task, where the behaviour is built into the task, and the task provides some properties which you can use to configure the behaviour. We have seen these in Chapter 15, More about Tasks. Most Gradle plugins use enhanced tasks. With enhanced tasks, you don't need to implement the task behaviour as you do with simple tasks. You simply declare the task and configure the task using its properties. In this way, enhanced tasks let you reuse a piece of behaviour in many different places, possibly across different builds.
>
> The behaviour and properties of an enhanced task is defined by the task's class. When you declare an enhanced task, you specify the type, or class of the task.